# Visual Studio 2010 loses user settings when run side by side

Tags: visual-studio-2010, settings

Since some time I register an annoying behavior in Visual Studio 2010 SP1 under Windows Vista. Sometimes my user settings are lost on start up. This happens most of the time, when I had open the same solution parallel in two instances of VS and after closing both, the settings are lost on the next start of VS.
I do not change settings while running the two VS.

Did anyone experience the same behavior?

Of cource I saved my settings, but especially my keyboard short cuts cannot be fully restored, because I overwrote some global default short cuts. So that's what bugs me about it most. ([EDIT] This is an independent problem, see [Microsoft Connect.](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/643973/error-importing-keyboard-settings-into-vs-2010))

Is there a way to get VS not to kill my settings on start?

Comment: Had the same problem here!! Wonder what makes VS drop those settings sometimes.

Comment: If you saved the settings and the keyboard shortcuts don't restore when you restore the saved settings then you have a much bigger problem.  Post to connect.microsoft.com, they'll need a repro so be sure to include your saved settings file.

Comment: @Hans Thanks, seems that the short cut problem is specific to the German VS only. See [Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/643973/error-importing-keyboard-settings-into-vs-2010)

Comment: Ah, yes, "Strg" causes problems here too :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9031233/vs2010-strg-pgup-pgdown-like-in-browsers

Answer (score 2):

VS overwrites user settings on close. If you want to avoid such problems, you should close an instance where you made changes last.

Comment: dmay, I don't change any settings while running the two VS. Added this to my question.