# VS2010: Ctrl-PgUp / -PgDown like in browsers

Tags: visual-studio-2010, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm trying to get the same navigation like in browsers in VS2010, so with `Ctrl` + `PgUp` I go to the previous window and with `Ctrl` + `PgDown` I go the next window in the tab bar. For this I changed the Shortcuts using Environment / Keyboard in Tools / Options. I changed the commands of Window.NextDocumentWindow and Window.PreviousDocumentWindow.

I can navigate using these keys now, but it doesnt't go the next/previous document in the tab list but to the document opened after/before the current one.

Window.NextDocumentWindowNav and PreviousDocumentWindowNav doesn't help, the list is always sorted by last focussed.

**More explanation**: I open the docs doc1, doc2, doc3, doc4, doc5. Now I the tablist I move doc5 between doc1 and doc2 and focus on doc1. When using `Ctrl` + `PgDown` now, doc2 is displayed, because it was opened right after doc1 but i want to go to doc5 which is right after doc1 in the tablist.

Anyone an Idea?

Comment: What does "Strg" mean?  Those are the correct commands.  You can use Window.NextDocumentWindowNav and PreviousDocumentWindowNav to get the behavior you describe.

Comment: Damn it, I ment Ctrl, I updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21027/changing-ctrltab-behavior-for-moving-between-document-in-visual-studio/4099033#4099033) question. Install the [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef) Extension and map the commands *Window.NextDocumentWellTab* and *Window.PreviousDocumentWellTab* (in German VS: *Fenster.NächsteRegisterkarte* and *Fenster.VorherigeRegisterkarte*) to your Keys.